# For Loop MovieClip Grid not showing on stage

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

So I'm a newbie and should obviously spend time in the tuts, but I'm looking for a quick answer. Basically, I've created a grid of movie clips with AS3. When I 'preview' the flash (as a flash or HTML) it shows up fine. Success. Yet, the stage remains empty.

Q1) Will the stage remain empty as I have used AS3 to dynamically 'draw' the grid of mc's? Or is there a slit of code I am missing to make this baby show up on the stage?

Q2) I've managed to use alpha to make the MC's 'fade' on hover - but I want to make them change color (to red) when hovered over. I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find the right script.

Here is my code:

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
 var image = new createjs.Bitmap("images/square.png");
 stage.addChild(image);
 createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick);
 function handleTick(event) {
     image.x += 10;
     stage.update();
 }

var x0:Number = 0;
var y0:Number = 0;
var nt:Number = 72;
var nc = 10;
var vd:Number = 12;
var hd:Number = 12;
for (var i = 1; i <= nt; i++) {
    var mc = this.attachMovie("square", "square" + i, i);
    var aprox = Math.floor((i - 1) / nc);
    mc._x = x0 + hd * ((i - aprox * nc) - 1);
    mc._y = y0 + aprox * vd;
    mc.useHandCursor = true;
    // fade in
    mc.onRollOver = function()
    {

        this.onEnterFrame = function()
        {
            if (this._alpha > 0) {
                this._alpha -= 10;
            } else {
                this._alpha = 0;
                delete this.onEnterFrame;
            }
        };
    };
    // fade out
    mc.onRollOut = function()
    {
        this.onEnterFrame = function()
        {
            if (this._alpha < 100) {
                this._alpha += 10;
            } else {
                this._alpha = 100;
                delete this.onEnterFrame;
            }
        };
    };

}
```

Thanks in advance - sorry I am a noob.

Answer (score 0):

This will never work. 1/3 of your code is in AS3, 2/3 in AS2. Considering you haven't been thrown any error, I assume you exported it as AS2.